# Strange grey line appearing tkinter when adding icon with root.iconbitmap

Tags: python, tkinter, winapi, tk-toolkit

Here is a MRE:

```py
import tkinter as tk

# Window
tkWindow: tk.Tk = tk.Tk()
tkWindow.resizable(False, False)
tkWindow.iconbitmap("icon.ico")

# Label Welcome
text: str = f"Wedfghhhhhhhhjkllllll hojjjjjjjjj hjjjjjjjjj V1."

label_welcome: tk.Text = tk.Text(
    tkWindow,
    height=1,
    width=len(text),
    background='SystemButtonFace',
    borderwidth=0
)
label_welcome.insert("current", text)
label_welcome.grid(row=0, column=1, columnspan=2, pady=15)

tkWindow.mainloop()
```

Running this will get you this:

[image]

And if you look closely there is a strange grey line on the top right of the image.

It disappears if I comment out the line `tkWindow.iconbitmap("icon.ico")`:

[image]

Here is the file I'm using (`icon.ico`) if it's important to reproduce the MRE.
https://wetransfer.com/downloads/26750bfab596b8bb74798c06a6c84e8820221228151614/3e2fe2

I'm using `Python 3.11.1` and `Windows 11`

Comment: What OS, version of Python, etc. Can't reproduce this on Windows with Python 3.7.5.

Comment: Can reproduce with an empty Window on Windows 11 and python 3.11, Might look into it later that day.

Comment: @Thingamabobs That link takes me to a website but no icon to download.

Comment: Remove `borderwidth=0` and let me know if that fixes it. I suspect this might be your issue due to how widgets are drawn.

Comment: So after playing around with this using some random ico file I got off the internet it appears to be a visual bug that shows up when the window is drawn but does go away and come back while moving the window around. I have also confirmed that this appears to only happen while using an ico file and a png file instead of letting tkinter use its default. I am going to say it is most likely going to have this behavior with any image you use as an icon and is simply a visual artifact. Not sure much can be done about it. All that said I also check to make sure the icons were multiples of 16 pixels.

Comment: Oddly enough I am unable to take screenshots or even do a print-screen as when I do this visual bug does not show up in the resulting image. I highly suspect its a visual bug that is not 100% on tkinter side but might even be a issue with how the computers graphics are drawing the image on screen.

Comment: @Mike-SMT did reproduce, as you already found out, with a random png file. I have two things in mind. First, it could be a Windows issue, for having an "extended client area", even I'm not aware of any functionality tkinter has in use. Second, tkinter if I recall correctly, uses a frame that is reparented by the window manager, and there is a parsed bounding box of the client area which is hard coded in tkinter, so a slightly change of one pixel, by Windows, for the title bar could break this message procedure. Both could be fixed with code that reaches into that, but would be fragile as befor

Comment: I'm suggesting, try to life with it, at this point. Cause a work around not coming from tkinter might break again in the future release of tkinter or Windows and you might get unintended behaviour by reaching this far into the Toolkit. Cause for some messages sent by the Window manager you only have a given time to react and python is not known to be fast, same applies to tcl/tk. If you want to do something, file a complaint that it get fixed in C-code rather than messing around with this low level stuff.

Comment: @Mike-SMT removing `borderwitdh=0` does not fix it.

Comment: @DanMašek I'm using `Python 3.11.1` and `Windows 11`.

Comment: @Mike-SMT Oh yes sorry, the file had expired. Sorry I couldn't answer earlier.

Answer (score 0):

I tried the your code with PNG image of same icon and added geometry for tkinter window, Grey line is disappeared

```
from tkinter import * 
from tkinter.ttk import *


tkWindow = Tk()   
iconImage = PhotoImage(file = 'icon.png')
#Set the Title of Tkinter window
tkWindow.title("Icon With Underline")
tkWindow.geometry("450x270")

# Label Welcome
text: str = f"Wedfghhhhhhhhjkllllll hojjjjjjjjj hjjjjjjjjj V1."

label_welcome: tk.Text = tk.Text(
    tkWindow,
    height=3,
    width=len(text),
    background='SystemButtonFace',
    borderwidth=0
)
label_welcome.insert("current", text)
label_welcome.grid(row=1, column=1, columnspan=2, pady=0)

tkWindow.iconphoto(False,iconImage)   

mainloop()
```

Comment: Do not both `import tkinter as tk` and `from tkinter import *`. Your better off just using `import tkinter as tk` only.

Comment: Sorry, my bad !!. I didn't notice that. I edited

Comment: If I remove `tkWindow.geometry("450x270")`, the grey line re-appears. So I believe it doesn't really have anything to do with the `.png` thing. (https://i.imgur.com/CZE9yr9.png)

Answer (score 0):

Replacing `tkWindow.iconbitmap("icon.ico")`

with

`tkWindow.wm_iconbitmap("icon.ico")` fixed the issue on a Windows 11 environment.

Could you check if this works for you?

Comment: Note that `iconbitmap()` is just an alias of `wm_iconbitmap()`, so they are the same.

Comment: Did not change anything for me which makes sense with @acw1668 comment.